Why is my firebase current user coming back null when I use getAuth
Users are required to verify an email link prior to logging in.  On the login screen I've created a 'resend link' button but using getAuth doesn't provide me with the currentUser details in order to resend the link.
Here's the inline onClick function:
<Link
  onClick={() => {
    const userAuth = getAuth(app);
    console.log('auth', userAuth)
  }}
  variant="body2"
  sx={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>
  Resend verification link
</Link>

When I click it the current user returns null.
I'm able login but when I logout and click the link it's not providing any user details.

Why are you expecting currentUser to be anything other than null after the user signs out?  A null currentUser is the very definition of no user signed in.  The SDK doesn't keep a record of users previously signed in.  All that data is deleted at the time of signout.

@DougStevenson I'm new to React.  I'm looking for an example on how to add a popup that allows the user to send another verification email after they attempt to login.  I'd have a condition that checks if the email has been verified and give the user the option to send another if it hasn't.  What's the best way to do that?

If your question is not what you've written but actually about looking for examples of how to do something, or opinions about the best way to do something, that's off-topic for Stack Overflow.  Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic It's expected that a post explain what the task is, show the code so far, and explain what isn't working as expected.  We can then tell you what you might be doing wrong, or correct a gap in your understanding.
